# How to get a derivative file that contains spaces?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

The API documentation on obtaining specific derivative file does not explain how to obtain derivative files with spaces.

I have tried replacing the spaces in my urn with with `%20`, `_`, `+` and `-` but none of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative uses the `base64` encoded version of the file name (i.e. objectName), which encodes the spaces properly.

Comment: oh, now that I've noticed, my problem wasn't with spaces as I manage to get files with spaces in their name.  I am not able to download 3 png image files that contains spaces and special character `+`, `_` and `-` (Error message returns 404), I am able to get the rest of the files even when they contain spaces. 
I guess that's another SO question for me after further testing. Thanks!